# Grizzly PRESERVE_HEADER_CASE

Tags: java, java-8, jersey, grizzly

I need to make Grizzly not alter the headers keys.

I found this property `PRESERVE_HEADER_CASE` but no idea where to configure

Any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Mule 3.8.1, this can be done by passing a system property

```
org.glassfish.grizzly.http.PRESERVE_HEADER_CASE=true
```

Java way:

```
public static final String PRESERVE_HEADER_CASE = "org.glassfish.grizzly.http.PRESERVE_HEADER_CASE";

public SystemProperty headerCaseProperty = new SystemProperty(PRESERVE_HEADER_CASE, "true");
```

Comment: Thanks,yeah I read that also. But want to know if there´s a better way to do it using the Grizzly or Jersey API

Comment: @paul Updated the answer with the same solution in Java.

Comment: Thanks what I was looking was in the API. I think this will also make it works         server.getListener("grizzly").getHttpCodecFilter().setPreserveHeaderCase(true);